# what is this box in visual studio called and how can it be disabled?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4lLIEmC.png]

In visual studio, this box shows up when the mouse hovers over code (in the screenshot it says "class ExampleClass")

What is this called and how do i turn it off?

Comment: Could it be CodeLens, not sure

Comment: i looked through the entire options list for the text editor and didnt see CodeLens, but thanks for the suggestion